# Finding the pre branch tag based on a branch name in CVS - is it possible?

Tags: version-control, tags, branch, cvs

I am new to a repository and all I have is a CVS branch name.  I am trying to determine the branch point or base point of this branch.  How can I find the pre-branch tag?  Is it possible?

To be more clear - the procedure to create a branch is as follows:

```
create base tag:
$ cvs tag BASE

Create branch:
$ cvs tag -r BASE -b BRANCH
```

Taking the above example I know BRANCH - I am trying to find BASE.  I have searched for quite a while and the only thing that comes up is how to create the pre-branch tag and branch (shown above), but nothing comes up on how to find out what the pre-branch tag is based on the branch name.

Thanks,
- Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the commmand

`$ cvs status -v {file}`

You get the tags for the `{file}`.

The output will be something like (in the end of it):

```
Existing tags:
    tag_name_1      (revision 1.1)
    BASE      (revision 1.2)
    BRANCH  (branch 1.2.1)
```

Then you'll know what is your branch revision, and the previous revision. In the example, you know your branch name (BRANCH). Its revision is 1.2.1. The previous is 1.2, and the tag for this revision is BASE.

Maybe the revision numbers in the example aren't in the way CVS do, but you can get the idea.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up figuring out a very similar solution to what you posted here and scripted it based on a script I pulled off of github.  The solution I came up with I posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16425841/1652375